# how do you create a script to plot multiple lat/lng from a query in cognos report studio using html

Tags: cognos

i have an working api key --

... just need a little guidance creating a script or loop to grab lat/lng from query and plotting onto a map in html format in cognos report studio

HTML ITEM -> SOURCE TYPE (TEXT)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

<!-- Reference to the Bing Maps SDK -->
    <script type='text/javascript'
            src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=[YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY]' 
            async defer></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function GetMap()
    {
        var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap');

    //Add your post map load code here.
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML ITEM -> REPORT EXPRESSION

```
<body onload="GetMap();">
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap');
```

Comment: What version of Cognos?

Comment: Cognos version 10.2.1